# Is there a topological version of Cayley's Theorem?

Tags: topological-groups

Given a topological group $G$ can we embbed it in $Aut_{TOP}(X)$ for some topological space $X$?

It is a good choice the open-compact topology for $Aut_{TOP}(X)$?

Comment: Since the usual proof gives an embedding in the group sense, I assume you mean an embedding in the topological sense?

Comment: Yes, in the topological sense.

Comment: $X = G$ should work fine at least if $G$ is locally compact Hausdorff. General topological groups are a mess, and so are general topological spaces, so...

Comment: Yes, [there is](https://sci-hub.hkvisa.net/10.2307/2321608)